# Run setup if .Net Framework not installed

Tags: c#, frameworks

How can i do something like that: when user starts my C# application if he dont have .Net framework installed then application start setup?

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly can it start setup for something that doesn't exist on their machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that because you application belongs to functionality of .Net.
What you need todo is to build a setup. Visual Studio itself brings a setup project or you can use e.g. inno-setup (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

EDIT:
Here is a useful project to use with inno-setup.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-1-1-2-0-3-5-Installer-for-InnoSetup